# How to map an Entity to Multiple tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Code First to a Existing Database, and have a Entity that I have to map to two tables, how can I accomplish that?

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier(
    SupplierId bigint identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    SupplierName varchar(60) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Customer(
    CustomerId bigint identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(60) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE SupplierPayments(
    SupplierPaymentNumber bigint NOT NULL,
    SupplierId bigint NOT NULL, 
    PaymentValue decimal(19,4)  NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE CustomerPayments(
    CustomerPaymentNumber bigint NOT NULL,
    CustomerId bigint NOT NULL, 
    PaymentValue decimal(19,4)  NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE SupplierPayments
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SupplierPayments
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SupplierPaymentNumber, SupplierId ASC);

    ALTER TABLE CustomerPayments
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerPaymentss
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerPaymentNumber, CustomerId ASC);
```

And my entities:

```
public partial class Supplier{
     public long SupplierId{ get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public virtual List<Payment> Payments{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer{
     public long CustomerId{ get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public virtual List<Payment> Payments{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Payment{
     public long PaymentNumber{ get; set; }
     public decimal Value{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I configure (with Fluent API) the many-to-one relationship between Supplier and Customer to Payment?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have troubles maintaining such a code. It could be wiser to remove Customer and Supplier classes altogether and add another entity called, lets say BusinessPartner:

```
public partial class BusinessPartner {
    public long Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public BusinessPartnerType Type {get; set; }
}

public enum BusinessPartnerType {
    Customer = 1,
    Supplier = 2
}
```

As of the SupplierPayments and CustomerPayments - these shall be replaced with one table as well, but you don't have to specify the type of payment since it is already specified in the BusinessPartner table.